# Spring cloud bus configuration to distribute configuration to all clients with one refresh

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to configure reliable configuration service that uses bus to update clients when config change happens. I started two config servers that monitors local file system. Two eureka servers, so that clients could discover config service at startup (i.e. eureka fist config type). I used rabbitMQ as a amqp bus.
Current behavior is the following: If I update config file and request post on http://config-server1/bus/refresh, config server sends notification and only one client picks it. So that to update 3 clients I need to make 3 posts.
Question: How can I configure bus so that one post to /bus/refresh will update all clients.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should work out of the box. What versions are you using? Can you paste a link to your code please?

Comment: Hi @Dave, there were too old versions. It works well for spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.2.RELEASE. Thank you for good question!